# NetCDF file with Lat/Lon as variables, not as coordinates

Tags: geotiff-tiff, netcdf

I am a beginner in using NetCDF files.
I would like to transform several NetCDF into GeoTIFF but the Lat/Lon info is in variables and not as dimensional coordinates. I can't work with these files.

I have tried with GDAL but these files are not georeferenced correctly.
The result from ncdump is below.

How can I do this?

```
netcdf C:/Users/USER/Desktop/net/01/MARC_B1-ECOMARS3D-MANGA4000_20220102T1200Z.nc {
  dimensions:
    ni = 245;
    nj = 266;
    ni_u = 245;
    nj_u = 266;
    ni_v = 245;
    nj_v = 266;
    ni_f = 245;
    nj_f = 266;
    time = UNLIMITED;   // (1 currently)
    level = 30;
  variables:
    float ni(ni=245);
      :long_name = "x-dimension of the grid";
      :standard_name = "x_grid_index";
      :c_grid_axis_shift = 0.0; // double
      :axis = "X";
      :c_grid_dynamic_range = "3:236";
      :_ChunkSizes = 245U; // uint

    float nj(nj=266);
      :long_name = "y-dimension of the grid";
      :standard_name = "y_grid_index";
      :axis = "Y";
      :c_grid_axis_shift = 0.0; // double
      :c_grid_dynamic_range = "3:265";
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U; // uint

    float ni_u(ni_u=245);
      :long_name = "x-dimension of the grid at u location";
      :standard_name = "x_grid_index_at_u_location";
      :c_grid_axis_shift = 0.5; // double
      :axis = "X";
      :c_grid_dynamic_range = "2:235";
      :_ChunkSizes = 245U; // uint

    float nj_u(nj_u=266);
      :long_name = "y-dimension of the grid at u location";
      :standard_name = "y_grid_index_at_u_location";
      :axis = "Y";
      :c_grid_axis_shift = 0.0; // double
      :c_grid_dynamic_range = "3:265";
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U; // uint

    float ni_v(ni_v=245);
      :long_name = "x-dimension of the grid at v location";
      :standard_name = "x_grid_index_at_v_location";
      :c_grid_axis_shift = 0.0; // double
      :axis = "X";
      :c_grid_dynamic_range = "3:236";
      :_ChunkSizes = 245U; // uint

    float nj_v(nj_v=266);
      :long_name = "y-dimension of the grid at v location";
      :standard_name = "y_grid_index_at_v_location";
      :axis = "Y";
      :c_grid_axis_shift = 0.5; // double
      :c_grid_dynamic_range = "3:265";
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U; // uint

    float ni_f(ni_f=245);
      :long_name = "x-dimension of the grid at f location";
      :standard_name = "x_grid_index_at_f_location";
      :c_grid_axis_shift = 0.5; // double
      :axis = "X";
      :c_grid_dynamic_range = "2:235";
      :_ChunkSizes = 245U; // uint

    float nj_f(nj_f=266);
      :long_name = "y-dimension of the grid at f location";
      :standard_name = "y_grid_index_at_f_location";
      :axis = "Y";
      :c_grid_axis_shift = 0.5; // double
      :c_grid_dynamic_range = "3:265";
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U; // uint

    double latitude(nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "latitude";
      :standard_name = "latitude";
      :units = "degrees_north";
      :_FillValue = 1.7E38; // double
      :valid_min = -90.0; // double
      :valid_max = 90.0; // double
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U, 245U; // uint

    double longitude(nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "longitude";
      :standard_name = "longitude";
      :units = "degrees_east";
      :_FillValue = 1.7E38; // double
      :valid_min = -180.0; // double
      :valid_max = 180.0; // double
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U, 245U; // uint

    double time(time=1);
      :long_name = "time in seconds (UT)";
      :standard_name = "time";
      :units = "seconds since 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z";
      :axis = "T";
      :time_origin = "01-JAN-1900 00:00:00";
      :conventions = "relative number of seconds with no decimal part";
      :_ChunkSizes = 512U; // uint

    float level(level=30);
      :long_name = "sigma level";
      :axis = "Z";
      :c_grid_axis_shift = 0.0; // double
      :positive = "up";
      :valid_min = -1.0f; // float
      :valid_max = 0.0f; // float
      :standard_name = "ocean_s_coordinate";
      :formula_terms = "s: level eta: XE depth: H0 a: theta b: b depth_c: hc";
      :formula_definition = "z(n,k,j,i) = eta(n,j,i)*(1+s(k)) + depth_c*s(k) + (depth(j,i)-depth_c)*C(k)";
      :_ChunkSizes = 30U; // uint

    double longitude_u(nj_u=266, ni_u=245);
      :long_name = "longitude at u location";
      :standard_name = "longitude_at_u_location";
      :units = "degrees_east";
      :valid_min = -8.07563352826511; // double
      :valid_max = 5.204288499025337; // double
      :_FillValue = 1.7E38; // double
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U, 245U; // uint

    double longitude_v(nj_v=266, ni_v=245);
      :long_name = "longitude at v location";
      :standard_name = "longitude_at_v_location";
      :units = "degrees_east";
      :valid_min = -8.07563352826511; // double
      :valid_max = 5.204288499025337; // double
      :_FillValue = 1.7E38; // double
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U, 245U; // uint

    double latitude_u(nj_u=266, ni_u=245);
      :long_name = "latitude at u location";
      :standard_name = "latitude_at_u_location";
      :units = "degrees_north";
      :valid_min = 43.131362467866325; // double
      :valid_max = 52.86863753213368; // double
      :_FillValue = 1.7E38; // double
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U, 245U; // uint

    double latitude_v(nj_v=266, ni_v=245);
      :long_name = "latitude at v location";
      :standard_name = "latitude_at_v_location";
      :units = "degrees_north";
      :valid_min = 43.131362467866325; // double
      :valid_max = 52.86863753213368; // double
      :_FillValue = 1.7E38; // double
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U, 245U; // uint

    float SIG(level=30);
      :long_name = "sigma variable";
      :standard_name = "ocean_s_variable";
      :units = ;
      :valid_min = -1.0f; // float
      :valid_max = 0.0f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 30U; // uint

    float Csu_sig(level=30);
      :long_name = "C(s) law at mid layer";
      :standard_name = "ocean_s_coordinate_function_at_midlayer";
      :units = ;
      :valid_min = -2.0f; // float
      :valid_max = 2.0f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :formula_definition = "C(k) = (1-b)*sinh(a*s(k))/sinh(a) + b*[tanh(a*(s(k)+0.5))-tanh(0.5*a)]/(2*tanh(0.5*a))";
      :_ChunkSizes = 30U; // uint

    float hc(nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "depth over which the resolution is increased";
      :standard_name = "ocean_s_coordinate_thick_of_surface_resolution";
      :units = "m";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -20.0f; // float
      :valid_max = 500.0f; // float
      :_FillValue = -999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U, 245U; // uint

    float b;
      :long_name = "bottom control parameter";
      :standard_name = "ocean_s_coordinate_bottom_control";
      :units = ;
      :valid_min = 0.0f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float

    float theta;
      :long_name = "surface control parameter";
      :standard_name = "ocean_s_coordinate_surface_control";
      :units = ;
      :valid_min = 0.0f; // float
      :valid_max = 20.0f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float

    float H0(nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "bathymetry relative to the mean level";
      :standard_name = "model_sea_floor_depth_below_geoid";
      :units = "m";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -50.0f; // float
      :valid_max = 10000.0f; // float
      :_FillValue = -999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U, 245U; // uint

    float HX(nj_u=266, ni_u=245);
      :long_name = "bathymetry at u-location relative to the mean level";
      :standard_name = "model_sea_floor_depth_below_geoid_at_u_location";
      :units = "m";
      :coordinates = "latitude_u longitude_u";
      :valid_min = -50.0f; // float
      :valid_max = 10000.0f; // float
      :_FillValue = -999.01f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U, 245U; // uint

    float HY(nj_v=266, ni_v=245);
      :long_name = "bathymetry at v-location relative to the mean level";
      :standard_name = "model_sea_floor_depth_below_geoid_at_v_location";
      :units = "m";
      :coordinates = "latitude_v longitude_v";
      :valid_min = -50.0f; // float
      :valid_max = 10000.0f; // float
      :_FillValue = -999.01f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 266U, 245U; // uint

    float XE(time=1, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "sea surface height";
      :standard_name = "sea_surface_height_above_geoid";
      :units = "m";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -50.0f; // float
      :valid_max = 50.0f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float SAL(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "salinity";
      :standard_name = "sea_water_salinity";
      :units = "1e-3";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -5.0f; // float
      :valid_max = 50.0f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float TEMP(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "temperature";
      :standard_name = "sea_water_potential_temperature";
      :units = "degrees_Celsius";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -5.0f; // float
      :valid_max = 50.0f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float suspended_inorganic_particulate_matter(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "suspended_inorganic_particulate_matter";
      :standard_name = "mass_concentration_of_suspended_matter_in_sea_water";
      :units = "g.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float nanopicoplankton_nitrogen(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "nanopicoplankton_nitrogen";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_nanoplankton_expressed_as_nitrogen_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float diatom_nitrogen(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "diatom_nitrogen";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_diatoms_expressed_as_nitrogen_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float dinoflagellate_nitrogen(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "dinoflagellate_nitrogen";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_dinoflagellates_expressed_as_nitrogen_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float microzooplankton_nitrogen(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "microzooplankton_nitrogen";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_microzooplankton_expressed_as_nitrogen_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float mesozooplankton_nitrogen(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "mesozooplankton_nitrogen";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_mesozooplankton_expressed_as_nitrogen_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float karenia_carbon(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "karenia_carbon";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_karenia_expressed_as_carbon_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float karenia_nitrogen(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "karenia_nitrogen";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_karenia_expressed_as_nitrogen_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float karenia_phosphorus(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "karenia_phosphorus";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_karenia_expressed_as_phosphorus_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float pseudonitzschia_nitrogen(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "pseudonitzschia_nitrogen";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_pseudonitzschia_expressed_as_nitrogen_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float pseudonitzschia_silicon(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "pseudonitzschia_silicon";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_pseudonitzschia_expressed_as_silicon_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float domoic_acid(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "domoic_acid";
      :standard_name = "mass_concentration_of_domoic_acid_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float colonial_phaeocystis_nitrogen(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "colonial_phaeocystis_nitrogen";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_colonial_phaeocystis_expressed_as_nitrogen_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float phaeocystis_cells_nitrogen(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "phaeocystis_cells_nitrogen";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_phaeocystis_cells_expressed_as_nitrogen_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float phaeocystis_mucus(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "phaeocystis_mucus";
      :standard_name = "concentration_of_phaeocystis_mucus_expressed_as_mass_in_sea_water";
      :units = "mg.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float ammonium(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "ammonium";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_ammonium_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float nitrate(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "nitrate";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_nitrate_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float dissolved_silicate(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "dissolved_silicate";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_silicate_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float dissolved_phosphate(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "dissolved_phosphate";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_phosphate_in_sea_water";
      :units = "micromole.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float dissolved_oxygen(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "dissolved_oxygen";
      :standard_name = "dissolved_oxygen_in_water_column";
      :units = "mg.l-1";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float cumulative_nanoflagellate_carbon_production(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "cumulative_nanoflagellate_carbon_production";
      :standard_name = "cumulative_nanoflagellate_production_expressed_as_carbon_in_sea_water";
      :units = "g.m-3_from_01jan";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float cumulative_diatom_carbon_production(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "cumulative_diatom_carbon_production";
      :standard_name = "cumulative_diatom_production_expressed_as_carbon_in_sea_water";
      :units = "g.m-3_from_01jan";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float cumulative_dinoflagellate_carbon_production(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "cumulative_dinoflagellate_carbon_production";
      :standard_name = "cumulative_dinoflagellate_production_expressed_as_carbon_in_sea_water";
      :units = "g.m-3_from_01jan";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float organic_nitrogen_benth(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "organic_nitrogen_benth";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_organic_detritus_expressed_as_nitrogen_in_benthos";
      :units = "mmole.m-2";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float biogenic_silica_benth(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "biogenic_silica_benth";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_organic_detritus_expressed_as_silicon_in_benthos";
      :units = "mmole.m-2";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

    float detrital_phosphorus_benth(time=1, level=30, nj=266, ni=245);
      :long_name = "detrital_phosphorus_benth";
      :standard_name = "mole_concentration_of_organic_detritus_expressed_as_phosphorus_in_benthos";
      :units = "mmole.m-2";
      :coordinates = "latitude longitude";
      :valid_min = -1.0E30f; // float
      :valid_max = 1.0E30f; // float
      :_FillValue = 999.0f; // float
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 30U, 266U, 245U; // uint

  // global attributes:
  :limi = 0; // int
  :lima = 244; // int
  :pasi = 1; // int
  :ljmi = 0; // int
  :ljma = 265; // int
  :pasj = 1; // int
  :lkmi = 1; // int
  :lkma = 30; // int
  :pask = 1; // int
  :global_imin = 0; // int
  :global_imax = 244; // int
  :global_jmin = 0; // int
  :global_jmax = 265; // int
  :Conventions = "CF-1.6 OCO-1.3.1 COMODO-1.0";
  :product_version = "1.0";
  :references = "http://www.previmer.org/";
  :easting = "longitude";
  :northing = "latitude";
  :grid_projection = "n/a";
  :distribution_statement = "Data restrictions: for registered users only";
  :institution = "IFREMER";
  :institution_references = "http://www.ifremer.fr";
  :data_centre = "DYNECO/PHYSED";
  :data_centre_references = "http://wwz.ifremer.fr/mars3d";
  :creation_date = "2022-01-04T07:44:53Z";
  :run_time = "2022-01-04T07:44:53Z";
  :history = "2022-01-04T07:44:53Z: creation";
  :model_name = "MARS";
  :arakawa_grid_type = "C1";
  :source = "MARS ECOMARS-V10";
  :southernmost_latitude = "43.2314";
  :northernmost_latitude = "52.7686";
  :latitude_resolution = "3.597440000000000E-002";
  :westernmost_longitude = "-7.9756";
  :easternmost_longitude = "5.1043";
  :longitude_resolution = "5.360000000000000E-002";
  :minimum_depth = "-2.490000";
  :maximum_depth = "5043.400";
  :depth_resolution = "n/a";
  :forecast_range = "n/a";
  :forecast_type = "n/a";
  :operational_status = "experimental";
  :data_type = "OCO straight grid";
  :format_version = "1.4";
  :netcdf_version = "4.1.2";
  :software_version = "MARC forecasting system v2";
  :contact = "cdoco-exploit@ifremer.fr";
  :quality_index = "0";
  :title = "MARC B1 ECOMARS3D MANGA4000 v2019 forecast";
  :product_name = "MARC_B1-ECOMARS3D-MANGA4000_20220102T1200Z.nc";
  :comment = "Use of Meteo-France ARPEGE HR meteorological data";
  :area = "MANGA";
  :start_date = "2022-01-02T12:00:00Z";
  :stop_date = "2022-01-02T12:00:00Z";
  :field_type = "1-daily";
}
```

Comment: Why do you need it as a geotiff?  What software are you using?  Does latitude and longitude look structured? It looks like a 4D ocean model defined on an Arakawa-C staggered grid.  the various latitude and longitude variables are 2D matricies locating the points on the staggered edges or whatever (u,v, rho) of the grids.  You could probably get a particular variable of interest out as point data with its matching latitude* and longitude* variable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late but, I encountered the same. Maybe you need to do a couple of adjustments to the code, but you will see the main idea behind it.

```
data = netcdf_file[element][variable_name]
print(data)
# Get latitude and longitude information
longitudes = data[:, 0]
latitudes = data[:, 1]
ash_values = data[:, 2]
# Define the geospatial metadata
lon_min = float(longitudes.min())
lon_max = float(longitudes.max())
lat_min = float(latitudes.min())
lat_max = float(latitudes.max())
# Create a regular grid of latitude and longitude points
lon_points = np.arange(lon_min, lon_max + resolution, resolution)
lat_points = np.arange(lat_min, lat_max + resolution, resolution)
# Ensure the grid sizes match the data size
num_lon_points = len(lon_points)
num_lat_points = len(lat_points)

so2_grid = np.full((num_lat_points, num_lon_points), no_data_value, dtype=data.dtype)

# Fill the grid with SO2 values at intersecting points
for i in range(len(latitudes)):
    lon_index = int((longitudes[i] - lon_min) / resolution)
    lat_index = int((latitudes[i] - lat_min) / resolution)
    if 0 <= lon_index < num_lon_points and 0 <= lat_index < num_lat_points:
        so2_grid[lat_index, lon_index] = ash_values[i]

out_var_dir = output_dir / source / variable_name
out_var_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
# Create a GeoTIFF file for the current flight level
output_file = out_var_dir / f'{source}_{variable_name}_{date}.tif'

# Define CRS and transform
crs = 'EPSG:4326'  # WGS 84
transform = from_origin(longitudes.min(), latitudes.min(), resolution, -resolution)  # Adjust resolution as needed

# Create and write to GeoTIFF
with rasterio.open(output_file, 'w', driver='GTiff', height=so2_grid.shape[0], width=so2_grid.shape[1], count=1,
                   dtype=data.dtype, crs=crs, transform=transform, nodata=no_data_value) as dst:
    dst.write_band(1, so2_grid)
```